# Get absolute coordinates of element inside SVG using JS

Tags: javascript, svg, ecmascript-6

Good time forum users. I apologize in advance for my English. I could not find the answer (I decided to ask the English-speaking audience).

Absolute positioning (coordinates) of an element nested in groups relative to the parent container ().

```html
<svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 1000 1000" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMin slice" x="0" y="0" tabindex="1">
  <g transform="translate(100 100)">
       <g transform="translate(100 100)"> 
            <circle r="50" cx="25" cy="25" fill="yellow" />
       </g>
  </g>
<svg>
```

I would like to get using ES6 + circle coordinates relative to SVG. That is x = 100 + 100 + 25, y = 100 + 100 + 25 for .

How can I get these coordinates? (can be up to an infinite nesting of groups). Thanks for helping.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Find the `cx` and `cy` values of the circle
2. Apply any transform that the circle has
3. Step up to each ancestor element and apply any tranforms found
4. Stop when you reach the root SVG element

```js
function getCirclePosition(circleElemId)
{
  var elem = document.getElementById(circleElemId);
  var svg = elem.ownerSVGElement;

  // Get the cx and cy coordinates
  var pt = svg.createSVGPoint();
  pt.x = elem.cx.baseVal.value;
  pt.y = elem.cy.baseVal.value;

  while (true)
  {
    // Get this elements transform
    var transform = elem.transform.baseVal.consolidate();
    // If it has a transform, then apply it to our point
    if (transform) {
      var matrix = elem.transform.baseVal.consolidate().matrix;
      pt = pt.matrixTransform(matrix);
    }
    // If this element's parent is the root SVG element, then stop
    if (elem.parentNode == svg)
      break;
    // Otherwise step up to the parent element and repeat the process
    elem = elem.parentNode;
  }
  return pt;
}


var pos = getCirclePosition("thecircle");
console.log("Coordinates are: " + pos.x + "," + pos.y);
```

```html
<svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 1000 1000" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMin slice" x="0" y="0" tabindex="1">
  <g transform="translate(100 100)">
       <g transform="translate(100 100)"> 
            <circle id="thecircle" r="50" cx="25" cy="25" fill="yellow" />
       </g>
  </g>
<svg>
```

**Update**

As @Vad0k pointed out, there is a simpler, but slighlty less accurate approach, that can be used instead:

```js
function getCirclePosition(circleElemId)
{
  var elem = document.getElementById(circleElemId);
  var svg = elem.ownerSVGElement;

  // Get the cx and cy coordinates
  var pt = svg.createSVGPoint();
  pt.x = elem.cx.baseVal.value;
  pt.y = elem.cy.baseVal.value;

  return pt.matrixTransform(getTransformToElement(elem, svg));
}


function getTransformToElement(fromElement, toElement) {
  return toElement.getCTM().inverse().multiply(fromElement.getCTM());
};


var pos = getCirclePosition("thecircle");
console.log("Coordinates are: " + pos.x + "," + pos.y);
```

```html
<svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 1000 1000" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMin slice" x="0" y="0" tabindex="1">
  <g transform="translate(100 100)">
       <g transform="translate(100 100)"> 
            <circle id="thecircle" r="50" cx="25" cy="25" fill="yellow" />
       </g>
  </g>
<svg>
```

Comment: It works. Thank you, I have to leave work. I'll test it tomorrow morning and mark it as a solution. I noticed that only recursion is necessary to sort through each parent. This is good.

Comment: Why not use `.getCTM()` to get the matrix in one step?

Comment: SVGGraphicsElement.getCTM(). I also looked in this direction initially, but it returns the converted coordinates from the viewBox to the viewport of the browser itself.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. `getCTM()` includes the `viewBox` transform. Which we don't want here.

Comment: I wouldn't have spotted that requirement from "relative to SVG", but if that is what was asked...interesting that the API has neither a method to get a transform relative to the `<svg>` element user space coordinates, nor one to retrieve the equivalent transform of a viewport element.

Comment: There used to be `getTransformToElement()`. But it has been removed :(

Comment: `SVGElement.prototype.getTransformToElement = SVGElement.prototype.getTransformToElement || function(toElement) {
  return toElement.getScreenCTM().inverse().multiply(this.getScreenCTM());  
};` - Here is the scenario, by the way, maybe someone will need polyfil

Comment: It would be nice if you combined your two functions "getCirclePosition" and "getTransformToElement" because it would make the code more simple.

Answer (score 1):

Obtain the childs and parents top and left and get the difference

```
const circleLeft = circleElement.getBoundingRect().offsetLeft
const circleTop = circleElement.getBoundingRect().top
const parentLeft = circleElement.parentElement.getBoundingRect().offsetLeft
const parentTop = circleElement.parentElement.getBoundingRect().top
const changeInX = parentLeft - cirleLeft
const changeInY = parentTop - circleTop
```

If you are registering events on this elements, Register them as capturing event rather than bubbling event by passing `true` as third argument to `addEventListener`

Answer (score 0):

I just found, that you can use [getBBox()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SVGGraphicsElement/getBBox) on a SVG element to get its visible rectangle.

```
var rect = document.getElementById("myrect");
var visibleRect = rect.getBBox();
console.log("x=" + visibleRect.x + ", y=" + visibleRect.y + ", width=" + visibleRect.width + ", height=" + visibleRect.height);
```